# macOS Mojave clean install installer doesn't start

Tags: macbook-pro, install, mojave

I wish to perform a clean install of macOS Mojave on my Mid 2013 MacBook Air. I am currently running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

I've done all the steps, from downloading the installer from the Mac App Store, to creating a bootable USB using the follow command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled -- /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app
```

Then I rebooted my Mac with the USB flash drive plugged in, holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, and got to the select boot media screen.

When I select the USB flash drive to start the installer, I got a black screen with Apple logo and a progress bar. That went well and fill the 100% bar, but then nothing happens.

I've already waited for like 4 hours with nothing happening.
[image]

I just want to format my Mac to have a fresh start without any junk files.

Can anybody help me with what's going wrong?

Comment: @NimeshNeema would you ask a question on meta if we should flag for redaction of serial numbers? Some people don’t want their images redacted, others do. It would be good to have agreement on this.

Comment: @bmike https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3460/redacting-post-to-hide-device-serial-number

Comment: You don't need a bootable installer to do a clean install, but the command to create one should be `sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled`